# Javascript function not working in browsers(but working fine in code snippet)

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm practicing straight from the MDN but for some reason this code isn't running in Chrome or IE. When you click the button, the function is not being called. It's a program that guesses the user input and says if it's right or wrong. Can someone please tell me what I did wrong? If you run this in code snippet it works perfectly fine. But for some reason it's not working properly in the browser.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

var guesses = document.querySelector(".guesses");
var lastResult = document.querySelector(".lastResult");
var lowOrHi = document.querySelector(".lowOrHi");

var guessSubmit = document.querySelector(".guessSubmit");
var guessField = document.querySelector(".guessField");

var guessCount = 1;
var resetButton;


function checkGuess() {

  var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
  if(guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Previous guesses: ';
  }
  guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';
 
  if(userGuess === randomNumber) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    lowOrHi.textContent = '';
    setGameOver();
  } else if(guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = '!!!GAME OVER!!!';
    setGameOver();
  } else {
    lastResult.textContent = "Wrong!";
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if(userGuess < randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
    } else if(userGuess > randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
    }
  }
 
  guessCount++;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();
}

guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);
```

```html
 <p class="guesses"> </p>
 <p class="lastResult"></p>
 <p class="lowOrHi"></p>

 <label for="guessField"> Enter a guess: </label> <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">

 <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="guessSubmit">
```

Comment: Either put the `script` block after `body` end tag or do this at `window.onload` or `document.onload` event.

Comment: Ok that's funny because it's not like I was really calling the function until the page was loaded anyways so that's weird. But thanks!

Comment: @gurvinder372– Ignore earlier comment.. Just correcting you — _Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`))_

Comment: @Shinji-san Is it not working correctly in the SO snippet here?

Comment: @Rayon Sure, I think SO's code does give some output but I doubt if that is the issue OP was facing earlier.

Comment: It works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/zaghnmms/1/ - except the browser is complaining that setGameOver function does not exist.

Comment: @gurvinder372– Are you talking about `error` after `10` clicks ?

Comment: Yes it works fine in the fiddle and in snippet. Anyways thank guys

Comment: @Rayon No, wasn't talking about logical error since he talked about working independently and not-working in browser.